# CodeIgniter/ion_auth 404 Not Found "The requested URL /ci/admin/user/login/ was not found on this server."

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, lamp, ion-auth

We are developing a Codeigniter project and stumbled upon this error on Linux. Supposedly if you go to http://localhost/ci/ you will be redirected to http://localhost/ci/admin/user/login/ and that would show a login page (written using ion_auth). This works as normal on both Mac and Windows using Xampp but it doesn't work on my Linux Mint that runs on Lamp (no Xampp). On my Linux it just says 404 Not Found on the tab head and on the page it says

```
Not Found

The requested URL /ci/admin/user/login/ was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

This is the routes.php file

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['admin'] = 'admin/dashboard';
```

The rest of the files can be seen here https://github.com/DarkPotatoKing/ci

Based on the routes to me it seems that everything is correct but somehow /ci/admin/user/login/ cannot be found. I've seen some solutions online that says you should change the capitalization (like an_example_file.php into An_example_file.php) but that didn't work. I've also found an answer that says delete a certain line in routes.php but I've checked and that line is not on the file.

Comment: I notice your dashbord controller file name not first letter uppercase it is like dashboard.php should be Dashboard.php

Comment: **CodeIgniter Naming Conventions.** Controller, Model and custom library file names must have a capitalized first letter. For example: `Myclass.php`
Class declarations must be capitalized. For example: `class Myclass`.
Class names and file names must match.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it  by setting up mod_rewrite for apache by following the instructions here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04